# Initializing component inside a home page in Ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a **Home Page**, inside that I have created one component `RecentlyViewedProductComponent`.

**My problem is:**

when I navigate to `/home` by using

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

the `ngOnInit()` inside `RecentlyViewedProductComponent` is not working. When I close the app and open it again, that only it is working .

How to solve this problem?

Comment: so its Parent-child condition or you are pushing `RecentlyViewedProductComponent` from `HomePage`?

Comment: @CodeChanger In home.page.html, I am using <app-recently-viewed-products></app-recently-viewed-products> like this

Comment: Can you post some code of HomePage HTML so we can get more idea on this?

Comment: <app-home-header></app-home-header>
<ion-content>
  <app-recently-viewed-products></app-recently-viewed-products>
</ion-content>

Comment: ok so is it a tab based app or normal navigation based app?

Comment: its a normal navigation based app.

Comment: If its a tab based app then `ngOnInit()` method will call only a single time while page initialized.

Comment: Can you add Home.ts  & RecentlyViewedProductComponent.ts code here ?

Comment: @CodeChanger I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: try with `ionViewWillEnter()` instead. refer to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using the right lifecycle event.

Have you looked at the documentation here:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

It says that `ngOnInit()` is:

> Fired once during component initialization. This event can be used to initialize local members and make calls into services that only need to be done once.

If you want it to be called every time you navigate to the home page then you want to replace this with something like `ionViewWillEnter()`:

> Fired when the component routing to is about to animate into view.

There is actually [some guidance at the end of the docs page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-life-cycle-method) that you might find interesting which explains when to use each life cycle method.